# Corda data tampering attempt

Tags: corda

I have run Corda IOU example, after scanning H2 databases I find table IOU_STATES in h2 databases. I changed value from 50 to 70. then refresh Ui but on UI it was still showing value 50...I need to know where corda store data actually in H2 or any local storage... How VaultQueryBy retrieves it from local or H2? How on UI its showing untampered value then?

Edit: After changing value in state through SQL statement, it doesn't reflect on UI. UI default call API which calls VaultQueryBy...My question is even after i changed value in DB how its still showing untampered value on same node...?

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

The actual state itself is stored in `NODE_TRANSACTIONS`, as part of the blob of the transaction that created it as an output.

Data about the state is also stored:

- In `VAULT_STATES`, as a blob
- In `VAULT_FUNGIBLE_STATES`, if it implements the `FungibleAsset` interface, as a blob
- In `VAULT_LINEAR_STATES`, if it implements the `LinearState` interface, as a blob
- In one or more user-defined custom tables if the state implements the `QueryableState` interface, as a set of human-readable fields

In the Example CorDapp:

- `IOUState` implements the `QueryableState` interface to store its data in human-readable form in a custom user-defined table called `IOU_STATES` (see https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/schema/IOUSchema.kt#L23)
- The UI is loading the data from the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table, by taking the transaction ID and output index from the `VAULT_STATES` to locate the correct state in the correct transaction blob

As a result, your changes are not being reflected on the front-end.

Comment: Hi @Joel Thnx for instant reply. As you said UI is loading data from VAULT_STATES I agree. Also you said that state stored in VAULT_STATES but when i scan table I haven't got any blob fields...How can VaultByQuey gather all transaction information and show on UI... Is there any documentation that may help me to understand concept much more in detail

Comment: @Joel NODE_TRANSACTIONS doesnt have any output index, only transaction ID, how does it map to vault_states?

Comment: Sorry, I've reworded above. The output index and transaction ID come from the VAULT_STATES table, not the NODE_TRANSACTIONS table.